# Why I have this warning in a Spring Boot pom.xml file? "Overriding managed version 1.5.9 for mariadb-java-client"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, spring-jdbc

I am not using Spring from a lot of time and I have the following doubt.

I have this **pom.xml** file related to a **Spring Boot** project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>excel-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Excel API with Spring Boot</name>
    <description>Spring Boot - working with Excel API</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Start of excel dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End of excel dependencies -->

        <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Start DB connectivity dependencies -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
          <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End DB connectivity dependencies -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have added the last dependencies section related to the connectivity to a **Maria DB** database, these linese:

```
<!-- Start DB connectivity dependencies -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.7</version>
</dependency>
<!-- End DB connectivity dependencies -->
```

On the last dependency (the Maria DB client) it give me the following warning message:

> Overriding managed version 1.5.9 for mariadb-java-client

What exactly means this message? It seems to me that in some way I should already have a more updated version of this client (provided by Spring). But where? I never imported this dependency before so why have I it?

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because your project will somehow extending the POM [`spring-boot-dependencies`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/7080e2e9203a5c8b6c0999cdfa23c961ac246f00/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml) through extending the parent POM `spring-boot-starter-parent`. And inside `spring-boot-dependencies` , it defines the version of many dependencies in [`<dependencyManagement>`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/7080e2e9203a5c8b6c0999cdfa23c961ac246f00/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L2453)  which the version of `mariadb-java-client` is [1.5.9](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/7080e2e9203a5c8b6c0999cdfa23c961ac246f00/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L133).

The purpose of [dependency management](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) is used to centralise all dependencies' related information. In this case, it defines a default version for a set of libraries such that if a children POM want to include these libraries , it does not need to specify the version for them inside their `pom.xml` as it is already defined in the parent 's `<dependencyManagement>`.

So, in the children project 's `pom.xml` , we can simply define

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.foo.bar</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo-bar</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

rather than

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.foo.bar</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo-bar</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.56</version>
</dependency>
```

It allows all projects that extending this parent pom will have consistent dependencies version.

So , if you specify the version of a dependency inside the children pom that is different from what define in the `<dependencyManagement>` , it will give you the following warning :

```
Overriding managed version X.Y.Z for foo-bar
```